# What's the best way to share and edit a PHP project in localhost?

Tags: php, github

I have a project in PHP and I work on three different computers, in two of them I use Windows 10 and XAMPP and in the third I use Ubuntu 20.04 with PHP and Mysql manually installed.

I shared on Google Drive the XAMPP htdocs folder that I use on one of the Windows 10 computers, however, access from other computers must be through localhost, not at: file:///G:/Anothers%20computers/My%20laptop/www/

For example, when I try to access the folder above, the php is not interpreted. Because access is not through localhost. Not to mention that as I said I use Windows and Ubuntu, and in the latter I don't use XAMPP.

Would GitHub be the easiest option to share a folder and use it on these 3 computers? Or is there a better option?

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing this code on three different machines, I would suppose that GitHub is a pretty good solution. With git you have a very good way in documenting your changes and also have the possibility to revert your latest changes. But you have of course every time you leave one machine to remember to commit and push the changes. And on the other machine you have to pull the changes before you continue working on the code.

But every machine needs it own way to interpret the code.

Comment: It's also possible to have one development server to let customer or every one to see the main result without going to developer PC. Git have web hook so every time on push or release with tag it can be use for send hook to dev. server and download the latest code automatically. Up voted this answer.